# Google Play Services 7.8 to Eclipse

Tags: android

I want to use the new Mobile Vision API for scanning a Barcode from a bitmap created by a Camera Preview. But i can't integrate the Play Services into my Project in Eclipse. How do you guys do it in Eclipse?

Comment: "But i can't integrate the Play Services into my Project in Eclipse" -- please explain completely and precisely what your problem is. "How do you guys do it in Eclipse?" -- by following [the instructions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: Properties > Android > Add > google-play-services_lib > OK > Apply is what i did. But i can't import these import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest "Google Play services" installed via the SDK Manager (looks like v26 is the latest), and make sure that you are using a copy of that latest version in your project.

Comment: I already have the latest Version

Comment: Go into the copy of `google-play-services_lib` that is in your project. Open the `google-play-services.jar` that is in `libs/` in a ZIP file browser. You should see the classes that you cite in there. If you do, then something is awry with your build path in the Eclipse project. If you do not see those classes in the JAR, then while you may have downloaded the latest Play Services SDK to your machine, the copy that your project is using is an older one.

Comment: I added external JARs support-design.jar and play-services.jar. Now i can import those but the App crashes. NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of Lcom/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/BarcodeDetector$Builder;

Comment: "I added external JARs support-design.jar and play-services.jar" -- the Design Support library and the Play Services library are not JARs. They are Android library projects.

Comment: Thanks, but it still dosen`t work